# Minify JS via PHP using regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex, minify

will anyone advise me about JS minification? I try to create it, but without success. We will show you on the example: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js`

**I want**

1. Remove all comments except http & https or inside strings
2. Merge the code into one line
3. Remove all unnecessary spaces

I have tried a lot of examples from the Internet, and it has always been a mistake. Not even any minifier I found did it without error, so I want to write a simple own minifier. I do not want to use any plugin. I just want a clean regex.

Can you try to minify this example as much as possible? Whether it's spaces, comments or some other improvement or trickery?

**So far I have this, and it does not work either**

```
    '(\/\/[^\n\]*[\n\r]+)' => ''
    '/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//' => ''
    '#[\r\n]+#' => ''
    '/ {2,}/' => ''
```

Comment: This is not a problem I would try to solve with *regular expressions* (see [Now You Have Two Problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)).

Comment: So what do you recommend for effective JS minify? I tried it a lot, but nothing worked as expected

Comment: Off-topic tool request. But [JShrink](https://github.com/tedious/JShrink) should do the job.

Comment: So is not the chance to do this with a regex? Just over some plugins?

Comment: Github search: `minify javascript [PHP]`: Top result: https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify A CSS & JavaScript minifier, in PHP. Removes whitespace, strips comments, combines files. Problem solved?

Comment: There is no way to do this reliable with RegExp. You need to parse or at least tokenize the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
 function sanitize_output($buffer) {
      $search = array(
          '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  
          '/[^\S ]+\</s',  
          '/(\s)+/s',
          '#[\r\n]+#'       
      );
      $replace = array(
          '>',
          '<',
          '\\1',
          ''
      );
      $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
      return $buffer;
    }
    ob_start("sanitize_output");
```

> include this at the top of your header.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll need multiple expressions if you want to do it with regular expressions:

1. Multiline comments

   [**`\Q/*\E[\s\S]+?\Q*/\E`**](https://regex101.com/r/NCyQMn/1)
2. Single line comments:

   [**`(?:http|ftp)s?://(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|//.+`**](https://regex101.com/r/NCyQMn/2)
3. Whitespace:

   [**`^\s+|\R\s*`**](https://regex101.com/r/NCyQMn/3)

---

In PHP (obviously you do not need to name your keys, just for the sake of verbosity):

```
<?php

$url = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js";
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$expressions = array(
    'MULTILINE_COMMENT'     => '\Q/*\E[\s\S]+?\Q*/\E',
    'SINGLELINE_COMMENT'    => '(?:http|ftp)s?://(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|//.+',
    'WHITESPACE'            => '^\s+|\R\s*'
);

foreach ($expressions as $key => $expr) {
    $data = preg_replace('~'.$expr.'~m', '', $data);
}

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: I get an error in console when I use it: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input ... I also received this error in my experiments

Comment: This won't work if you have comments inside strings. For example, your first regex removes the comment inside `"This is /*a commment*/ inside a string"`, so `console.log("This is /*a commment*/ inside a string")` won't have the same behavior before and after being minified. You need to check whether the comments (and other stuff you want to change) are inside strings, which is complicated.

Comment: This is also not work if you have double slash inside strings. For example: `console.log('this is //in-line comment in js.');`.

Comment: @Jan Your logic will fail if you have only two slashes (single line comment) but no other character after that (not even a whitespace). In that case, the second expression would not catch it and the third expression would then move the rest of the content to the same line, making it a single line comment. Tested on your fiddles.

Comment: @LukasKroess: Hi Lukas, thanks for the update. The post is five years old but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the desired answer, but caddy server do minification on the fly. It is very easy to setup and provide green lock https automagically too.

Example Caddyfile, with cors, minification, logging, gzip compression, over php.

```
mysite.com {
    root ./mysitefolder/
    gzip
    log ../mysite.log
    minify /
    cors
    fastcgi / /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock {
        ext .php
        split.php
        index index.php
    }
}
```

https://caddyserver.com/docs/http.minify

Comment: I look at it, but I do not get it. Could you write a script in php how to use this? When I do this on localhost, I'll have to install it on the server too, right?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, but setting the php in caddy does not work. I have localhost on windows, would you help to enable PHP support?

Comment: No idea about windows, but i saw this: https://github.com/caddyserver/examples/tree/master/winphp . Try to replace the line  fastcgi with c:\path\to\php\php-cgi.exe { and also backlash antislash in path are source of issues.